# How to confirm AWS SNS subscription on a cell phone/in a text message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to send critical RDS events to our cell phones. I'm using the [phonenumber]@[carrier]format when setting them up. SNS (rightfully) wants a confirmation of the subscription by clicking on a link. The problem I'm seeing is the text message that SNS sends cuts off partway through the ARN and no link is ever shown.

I've tried manually confirming the subscription in the SNS console, but that requires a URL as well.

How do I confirm an SNS subscription via a text message?

Alternatively, how can I get critical RDS events sent to my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNS [supports SMS directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_manage.html) in [these regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html).

Comment: Ah, you don't use the email topic in the RDS subscription, you use the ARN then use SNS. Got it. Thanks.